# Installed pip 3 but when I run pip -version wont run

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, nvidia, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm working with a jetson nano which had python2.6 and 3.6 preinstalled. I installed python3.7 through `sudo apt install python3.7-dev`

When I tried to run the pip command, it said there was no such command. So I installed pip and pip 3 through:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Output:

```
 pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.7)
```

So it worked fine. But pip3 and pip stopped working after I downloaded the python dependencies to install mxnet via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y \
                        build-essential \
                        git \
                        libopenblas-dev \
                        libopencv-dev \
                        python3-pip \
                        python-numpy

sudo pip3 install --upgrade \
                        pip \
                        setuptools \
                        numpy
```

It says that '-bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory'

I'm not really sure what went wrong. Even when I retry to install pip or pip3 the same error comes out.

Comment: Wait a minute, [`sudo pip install` is bad practice](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/301745). Could you use `pip install --user` or a virtual environment instead?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.